# Receiving emails and moving them to a sidekiq queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, message-queue, sidekiq, mail-server

I have a messaging application app on my website (frontend + API) where users can send messages to each other.

Currently each time a message is entered via the form and sent to my API, my backend's `MessageService` kicks in, and does many things including sending an email notification to the other party.

I'd like to implement a system where the user can directly reply to the email, and somehow this would be processed by my app's `MessageService` just like if the message was sent via a POST from my frontend app.

In order to do this, I was thinking of of the following TODO

1. First setup a custom mail domain like `@mail.example.com`
2. Find a a service (either pay some SASS or setup some mail server myself) that would receive emails sent to this address. Ideally, it would be cloud/AWS-based
3. Forward all incoming emails to one of my redis / sidekiq queues
4. Have workers written in my favorite language (Ruby/Rails) read the message from my queue, so I can then forward all the logic processing to my `MessageService`

Do you have hints on how I could achieve 2 and 3 (forward received emails to a sidekiq queue)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Rails, Rails 6 is the next release and it will include ActionMailbox which has a similar purpose as you described.

Check the bleeding edge guide https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html While it's unreleased and you may be using something else, you can get ideas from their implementation.

In the guide several adapters are mentioned, one of them is using [Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-notifications.html) you simply connect receiving emails to an endpoint in your application that would then, process the request, persist the data for later usage and schedule the worker, something like: `MessageServiceWorker.perform_async(message.id)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Actually I'm not a big fan of the application endpoint as this implies that if the app is down, then the message would be lost, hence why I was rather thinking of a lambda + Push to Redis queue integration for better resilience.

Comment: You can very likely connect SES to SQS, If not directly, indirectly using SNS. Then your application polls for messages from SQS.